# Warning: include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/admin/web/

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Im receiving this error on my wordpress site.

> Warning: include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/admin/web/purfectcar.com/public_html/wp-config.php on line 53
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '1' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/purfectcar.com/public_html/wp-config.php on line 53

yesterday i did a clamav clean up im not sure if that is what cause the error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is on the line 53 of the `wp-config.php` file?

Comment: This is not an error its Warning.You can hide this via define(WP_DEBUG,false);

Comment: @JiriHrazdil is where the secret key list starts (define('AUTH_KEY', )

Comment: @VasimVanzara where exactly do i put that?

Comment: Inside wp-config.php.And Yes your live site not display anything.

Comment: I found the issue. it had an empty include command somewhere. deleted and its fine now. thanks for the feedback guys.

Comment: I have an advice for you please (WP_DEBUG,false);

Answer (score -3):

Warning: 
Displays a that you have file which is not in place of following path,

```
Warning: include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/admin/web/purfectcar.com/public_html/wp-config.php on line 53

Warning: include(): Failed opening '1' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/purfectcar.com/public_html/wp-config.php on line 53
```

Solution :

**Case 1:** Remove include statement if you are not need that.

**Case 2:** Place a file at location which is suggested.

**Case 3:** Make wp_debug  flag value off.You can found it in wp-config.php at root.

Comment: Was looking for an answer to this. But, obviously Case 1 makes no sense. One needs the include or require, CAse 2, the file IS there. Case 3 does not apply to non-WP sites.